# Find mirror point in unusual plane

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

I was working on an assignment and I ran into this weird curve-ball situation where part of it is to find the mirrored point of $P=(3,10,9)$ in the plane $x-z=0$. I can see the plane is basically the x-axis stretching the z-axis.

So I start by doing the usual $r(t) = P + t(n)$ figuring it will give me $t$($n$ being the normal in the plane, so $n = (1,0,-1)$).
But this is what happens:

$r(t) = (3,10,9) + t(1,0,-1)$

$<=> (3,10,9) + (t, 0, -t) $

$<=> x=3+t, y=10+0, z=9-t$

Then inserted into the plane:

$x-z=0 $

$<=> (3+t)-(9-t)=0 $

$<=> 3+t-9-t=0 $

$<=> -6=0$

In a gaussian elimination this would mean there is no solution, but what does it mean here? And how do I find the mirrored point now that I didn't find **t**?

Surely it can't just be that the mirror point is (-3,10,9)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in $(3+t)-(9-t)=0$
$$3+t-9+t=0$$$$2t=6$$$$t=3$$
$$x=3+t\implies3+3=6$$$$y=10$$$$z=9-t\implies9-3=6$$
$$(x,y,z)=(6,10,6)$$